# Bundle multiple safeTransferFrom calls into single transaction

Tags: blockchain, solidity, metamask

is there a chance to bundle multiple NFT transfers into single transaction so user has to confirm only once? I am trying to implement bulk NFT transfer function

```
    for(let i = 0; i < nftCount; i++) {
      contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(from, to, userNFT[0][i]).send({ from: account });
    }
```

This works great, but user has to approve every transfer and if he tries to transfer 100 NFTs it is very annoying and expensive gas.

Are there any better ways to do that bulk transfer on single go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the collection contract doesn't support bulk transfers, you can implement a custom contract that bulks them into one transaction.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC721 {
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external;
}

contract BulkTransferer {
    IERC721 collection;

    constructor (address _collection) {
        collection = IERC721(_collection);
    }

    function bulkTransfer(address _from, address _to, uint256[] memory _tokenIds) external {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _tokenIds.length; i++) {
            collection.safeTransferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenIds[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Because the invoker of the `safeTransferFrom()` function (on the collection) is now your `BulkTransferer` contract address (and not the user), the user needs to **approve** your contract to transfer their tokens before performing the actual transfer.

Either by executing the `approve()` function multiple times, once for each token ID. Or a less safe option - by executing the `setApprovalForAll()` giving the `BulkTransferer` contract address approval to transfer **any** of the user's tokens.

Comment: Seems like this is working for small bulk transfer, but if I try to do bulk of 100 NFTs it fails to calculate gas properly and it runs out of gas. How can I make sure that enough gas is suggested to pay by user so it does not run out of gas? On web3 I do not modify gas, I just call send({ from: account })

Comment: Ok, I managed to add custom gas calculation, but it exceeds block gas limit, so I will just limit transfer amount. Thank you so much for help

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with the problem of multiple `approve` for NFT transfer, then I suggest you could take a glance at the `setApprovalForAll`.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-setApprovalForAll-address-bool-

The function describes that you could authorize the contract (maybe a marketplace) you trust to transfer all the NFT tokens you own on your behalf. Therefore, you don't need to do "approve" for each token.

Answer (score 0):

you can use: https://metasender.co (It's easier )

It's an application created for that ;)

I also share their YouTube channel where you can find the process to send your Tokens/NFTs in bulk (step by step) for **Ethereum, Avalance, Binance smart chain, Polygon, and Fantom blockchain** (in ERC-20, ERC-721, and ERC-1155).

-> https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPsoDhYxwLd4Fw0lB7jGwDQ

I also advise you to ask them questions on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/metasender_bulk), they are reactive!